# Keeping application shortcuts from actually being stored on c:

Tags: windows-7, installation, desktop, symbolic-link

All programs want that front row seat called the Desktop to put their shortcut or shortcuts on.

Some programs do ask if you want a shortcut created.  Others don't.

So how can I create a symbolic link where any application shortcut is redirected to a drive other than C (boot/windows drive).  I would still like to be able to create my own shortcuts (via drag drop)

I am not a programmer so please don't assume I know any abbreviations or short command list.

Thank you for any help and for your time in reading this and or helping me.

Comment: Short answer: Not possible

Comment: Thank you Mr. Postill!  I could not find best answer or answered option for comments so I don't know if moderators will simply assign you the points for answering the question.